# Load Gallery images in Viewcontroller of iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

am new to iPhone and i have been given a task to show all the images from the gallery of the iPhone to the current view so that the user can select an image and view it and here's the second part of my problem i am having a share button and its functionality is that the selected image by the user on the touch of the share button must be shared on facebook.

Please help me regarding this,

Answer (score 1):

To select image from photo library use UIImagePickerController, here's an example:
http://www.zimbio.com/iPhone/articles/1109/Picking+Images+iPhone+SDK+UIImagePickerController

To integrate facebook in your app, you'll use facebook ios sdk:
http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

**Edit 1:**

Ok, here's the link for uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate whose method you'll use to get the image, it's really not that hard:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069

Here's the demo for facebook connect:
[link text](http://vimeo.com/3616452)

Comment: am using sdk 3.1 and the method named  (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
    didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
    editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo is no longer used so is their any alternate method to this

Comment: also the link you gave for facebook is not having any demos